# FFmpeg conform DASH to YouTube Live Stream requirements

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to stream to YouTube using FFmpeg and DASH. I've generated the stream key and I'm successfully sending the generated files to YouTube. However, YouTube refuses the MPD manifest because it has two AdaptationSet (one for video and one for audio), and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/encoding-with-dash#iso-bmff-segments) specifies that I should use only one for both video and audio

I've tried to use the `-adaptation_sets` flag unsuccessfully, and also the `-map` flag.

Here is one of the commands I've tried:
`ffmpeg -re -i "/Users/user/Desktop/file.mp4" \        -map 0:v -map 0:a \        -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -window_size 5 -min_seg_duration 5000000 \        -f dash dash.mpd`

And with the `-adaptation_sets` flag:
`ffmpeg -re -i "/Users/aniolpages/Desktop/2023-09-03 Taller colar filtrar assubtilar.mp4" -map 0 -map 0 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 \ -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 \ -window_size 5 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \ -f dash dash.mpd`

Has someone been successful to conform the manifest to YouTube requirements?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v,a"`